# Why not use require() in place of assert()?

Tags: solidity, require, assert

Even though `require()` is used substantially more than `assert()`, there are places where `assert()` gets used.
One example would be in the widely adopted `SafeMath` library by OpenZeppelin:

`function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
   c = a + b;
   assert(c >= a);
   return c;
}`

where `a + b` is checked after summation to prevent overflow.

It seems like `require(c >= a)` can be used in place of `assert(c >= a)` for same functionality with an additional opportunity to refund unused gas. Are there any reason not to use `require()` here? Is `assert()` used just to force people not to perform operations that result in bad consequences like overflow/underflow?

Cheers

Comment: I would use it to punish a user that sends wrong arguments on purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`require` is for making sure that an illegal input has not been passed to the function.

`assert` is for making sure that something which is never supposed to happen - does not happen.

In other words, `require` is for when you want to protect from a possible scenario, and `assert` is for when you want to protect from an impossible scenario (i.e., a bug in your code).

Think of `assert` as something that you would ultimately remove if you were 100% certain that your code was flawless.

Comment: Even "when you want to protect from an impossible scenario" why not just use `require`?

Answer (score 4):

Prior to the Byzantium network upgrade, require() and assert() actually behave identically, but their bytecode output is slightly different.

assert() uses the 0xfe opcode to cause an error condition
require() uses the 0xfd opcode to cause an error condition

**A very important the primary difference between the opcode is that assert() will cost you gas while require() will not!**

Please take a look at the very detailed and great description at:

https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on the differences between require() and assert() but you did not answer my question directly. My question is why not use require() in place of assert() since it can save user's gas even when something goes wrong. I have a similar idea with siid that assert() can be used to force people not to perform operations that result in bad consequences like overflow/underflow. @goodvibration had a good explanation on it.